# Why does my output only print if there is another print after it?

Tags: c, printf

Interesting little bug here:

```
if (host != NULL) {
    printf("hi");
} else {
    printf("FAIL");
}
return 0;
```

doesn't print anything at all, but:

```
if (host != NULL) {
    printf("hi");
} else {
    printf("FAIL");
}   
fprintf(stdout, "\n%s\n", (char *)&additionalargs);
return 0;
```

prints

> hi
>
> abc

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the \n characters.

As you printf characters, they are accumulated in a buffer which isn't sent to the output device until an 'end of line' character is sent.

Comment: It doesn't have to be end of line. Otherwise, there'd be no way to output and receive input on a single line.

Answer (score 7):

printf output to stdout is buffered. You might want to look at [fflush](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/fflush.html)

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines (ie `printf` is buffered).  I've only been at C for a week now.

Answer (score 0):

try using `fflush(stdout)` before your `if` condition.

Comment: wouldn't I want that AFTER my if condition? `man fflush` says that `fflush()` forces a write on whatever output stream is given as an argument.

Comment: to get exact output, better would be place fflush both before and after if condition, otherwise previous existent data of buffer may also be printed out.

Comment: it is going to be printed out anyway.  `fflush()` before `if` isn't going to magically make the previous unprinted data go away!

Comment: How does adding just a '\n' in printf magically prints the buffer. I guess, (and sorry for guessing ;lol) '\n' traditionally acted like line feed and made the buffer flush before printing a new line.

Comment: Manav, on many systems, `stdout` is line buffered.  Which means that printing a newline character flushes the buffer (or if the buffer becomes full).  However, if you really want your output to be visible at certain points, you should call `fflush(stdout);` after doing any printing that doesn't involve newline.