# Linux: combing sleep() with signals

Tags: linux, signals, sleep

Do you know where I can see a list of signals and functions that cannot be used alongside sleep() command?

For example, you can see this code:

```
// this program presents how to block signal SIGINT
// while running in critical region
#include    <signal.h>
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <unistd.h>
#include        <stdlib.h>
#include        <stdio.h>

static void sig_int(int);

int main(void)  //6
{
  sigset_t  newmask, oldmask, zeromask;

  if (signal(SIGINT, sig_int) == SIG_ERR)
    fprintf(stderr,"signal(SIGINT) error");

  sigemptyset(&zeromask);

  sigemptyset(&newmask);
  sigaddset(&newmask, SIGINT);

  /* block SIGINT and save current signal mask */
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr,"SIG_BLOCK error");

  /* critical region of code */
  printf("In critical region: SIGINT will be blocked for 3 sec.\n");
  printf("Type Ctrl-C in first 3 secs and see what happens.\n");
  printf("Then run this program again and type Ctrl-C when 3 secs elapsed.\n");
  fflush(stdout);


  sleep(3);

  printf("end sleep");
  /* allow all signals and pause */
  if (sigsuspend(&zeromask) != -1)
    fprintf(stderr,"sigsuspend error");

  printf("after return from sigsuspend: ");

  /* reset signal mask which unblocks SIGINT */
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
    fprintf(stderr,"SIG_SETMASK error");

  /* and continue processing ... */
  exit(0);
}

static void sig_int(int signo)
{
  printf("\nIn sig_int: SIGINT\n"); fflush(stdout);
  return;
}
```

The program doesn't wake up after the sleep(). Do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure it gets as far as sleep?.  It might be hanging on fflush(stdout), e.g. if disk is full or some other factor prevents fflush from completing.

Comment: How do you know it "doesn't wake up"?  You are perhaps [suffering from buffering](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2160469/132382) and need a newline in your printf() (or an fflush()) if you're running this from a line-buffered terminal.

Comment: @pilcrow, You're right! Addition of a newline character DID solve this problem. Can you give me a link to some explainations about "line-buffered terminal"?

Answer (score 0):

If you use strace, you can see what your program actually does

strace ./my-sig-program

If sleep never returns, I guess that task has received a SIGSTOP (this one can not be intercepted) or SIGTSTP (this one you can intercept with a signal handler), causing the OS the halt the entire process, until a SIGCONT is received.